# IOS: Dictionary Return null value/Data

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, nsdictionary

in my project i am using JSON parsing to display data for this i created 2 NSDictionary dictionary 1 return success response but when i call it in second dictionary it return Null value.
i am sharing my code please help me to correct it

```
-(void)hdata
{



    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data[Users][ref_id]=%@&api_key=bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6",refidstr];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.20/hspCh/api/user_diagnose_list"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"str : %@",str);



    NSDictionary *dict6 = [self cleanJsonToObject:responseData];
    NSLog(@"str : %@",dict6);    <=======it gives correct responce



    diagnosisdict = [dict6 objectForKey:@"data[Users][ref_id]"];

    [diagnosisdict setValue:refidstr forKey:@"data[Users][ref_id]"];
    NSLog(@" for ref id =%@ ,  data is= %@",refidstr, diagnosisdict);  <======Gives null responce

}
```

Output of the above in console is as follows

```
2015-12-09 10:34:16.935 HcH[2841:32315] str : {"response":200,"diagnoses":[{"DiagnosesHospitals":{"hospital_id":"3341","id":"163075","discharges":"100.00","charge_amt":"1200.00","total_amt":"1500.00","medicare_amt":"1200.00"},"Diagnoses":{"diagnosis_name":"TRANSIENT ISCHEMIA"}}]}
2015-12-09 10:34:16.935 HcH[2841:32315] str : {
    diagnoses =     (
                {
            Diagnoses =             {
                "diagnosis_name" = "TRANSIENT ISCHEMIA";
            };
            DiagnosesHospitals =             {
                "charge_amt" = "1200.00";
                discharges = "100.00";
                "hospital_id" = 3341;
                id = 163075;
                "medicare_amt" = "1200.00";
                "total_amt" = "1500.00";
            };
        }
    );
    response = 200;
}
2015-12-09 10:34:16.936 HcH[2841:32315]  for ref id =3341 ,  data is= (null)
```

Comment: Did you init your diagnosisdict? And why did you set key for this dic is "data[Users][ref_id]". This is a string, not value.

Comment: Looks like diagnosisdict  is not initialized.Its is not even print object and memory location.As per JSON, there is no data[Users][ref_id] keys. Please user [link](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to analyze JSON objects.

Comment: @CongTran data[Users][ref_id] is a request parameter by the help of which i ret the API response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
diagnosisdict = [dict6 objectForKey:@"data[Users][ref_id]"];
```

with

```
diagnosisdict = [[[dict6 objectForKey:@"diagnoses"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"DiagnosesHospitals"];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no entry in `dict6` for "data[Users][ref_id]".

Using that string as a key is completely nonsensical, by the way. A key in this context is just a  string, not a series of accesses in dictionaries.

It seems like what you want is `dict6[@"data"][@"Users"][@"ref_id"]`.

However, this will also fail, because there is no entry for "data" in `dict6`.

It is possible that your `cleanJSONToObject:` method is stripping out the value of the "data" key. However, based on your statement that printing the value of `dict6` gives the correct response, I assume that what you actually want to access is the value of "id" in "DiagnosesHospitals", since it sounds the most like a "ref_id".

Based on the output of the debugger, it seems as though you have a dictionary (dict6) with a "diagnoses" key pointing to an array with two dictionaries.

So, You would access the "id" field with `dict6[diagnoses][0][@"DiagnosesHospitals"][@"id"]`, assuming that "id" is a string (I'm not sure why it has no quotes around it).

Answer (score 1):

Somethings that you can get:

```
NSDictionary * diagnoses = dict6[@"diagnoses"];
NSString * diagnosis_name = diagnoses[0][@"Diagnoses"][@"diagnosis_name"];
NSDictionary * diagnosisdict = diagnoses[0][@"DiagnosesHospitals"];
NSString * hospital_id = diagnosisdict[@"hospital_id"];
```